# Parsing JSON format

Tags: python, json

I need help. I want to print all `pageid`,`title` from json format using `for loop`. Can anyone help? thanks

```
   {"query":
{"categorymembers":[{"pageid":13012551,"ns":0,"title":"List of Indian Punjabi films"}
,{"pageid":13662758,"ns":0,"title":"List of Punjabi language films"},
{"pageid":4628722,"ns":0,"title":"Ae Fond Kiss..."},
{"pageid":32991974,"ns":0,"title":"Aik Aur Ghazi"},
{"pageid":24605022,"ns":0,"title":"Asa Nu Maan Watna Da"},
{"pageid":21467628,"ns":0,"title":"Asoo Billa"},
{"pageid":17757556,"ns":0,"title":"Chaddian Di Doli"},
{"pageid":21369620,"ns":0,"title":"Chadi Jawani Budhe Nu"},
{"pageid":32012994,"ns":0,"title":"Chak De Phatte"},
{"pageid":13664636,"ns":0,"title":"Chann Mahi (1956 film)"}]}}
```

Comment: Why not regex any numbers after "pageid": until comma, then regex all characters after "title": until }. if you don't know regex well you can use http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp and paste in your json and read the help at the bottom until u get what u need.

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation for `json` (or if you have Python<2.6 `simplejson`) package? Actually, this particular piece of code will be about 5 lines... I can give an example, but it's really nice how this package works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - In python 2.6.1 there is a module called [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) this parses json string in python objects

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

data = json.load(json_data)
pprint(data)

for category in data['query']['categorymembers']:
    print 'PageID: %d and Title: %s' % (category['pageid'], category['title'])
```

Comment: Thanks Its working. I was tried like this `for c in data: print c['query']['title']` Thanks